# How can I access the Windows registry from Linux?

Tags: windows

I have a dual boot system. The need arised to look into the Windows registry on the Windows partition without prior rebooting. How can that be done?

Comment: A Google search turns out [this site](http://www.pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/).  See also [this](http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Windows_Registry)

Comment: Debian-based systems have `hivexsh` in a package: `sudo apt install libhivex-bin`.

Answer (score 7):

I found this :
http://linux.die.net/man/1/hivexsh

And, the hivex library comes with bindings for OCaml, Perl, Python and Ruby.